# How can I make my jquery mobile collapsible set larger using css

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a collapsible set for some of my data:

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">
     <div data-role="collapsible">
         <h1>
            <span style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; white-space: pre-wrap;" id="title">This is a really long book title</span><br>
            <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal;" id="author">This is the Author of the book</span>
            <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic;" id="year">Yr</span>
         </h1>
         <div>Statis</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I can't figure out how to change the height of each clickable box (the Title and Author). Apparently jquery mobile uses header tags to figure out what should be in the collapsible set before it's clicked (I think?). Because of that, I'm not able to apply any css.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/k9ocb8sg/)

Comment: actually I may have figured something out. By wrapping my header tags around a div and changing the div, I'm about to make the box bigger. However, my text is at the top of the box now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of each clickable box depends on the `padding-top` and the `padding-bottom` applied to the `.ui-btn` element. You can increase/decrease it by specifying the following CSS inside your stylesheet:

```
.ui-btn {
    padding-top: 2.7em;
    padding-bottom: 2.7em;
}
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k9ocb8sg/3/)**.

Comment: yep that worked great. My text is centered and the box is bigger. thanks

Comment: @RDoolabh this will affect all elements with `.ui-btn`, you should be specific as to which elements that rule should apply.